# How do I generate unique identifiers for responses from multiple forms, linked to a single Google spreadsheet?

Tags: google-sheets, google-forms

I have linked multiple Google forms to a single Google spreadsheet (each one to a new tab in the sheet) and I now want each response be assigned a unique identifier when it is received.

I've tried methods on here that generate sequential numbers based on the row, but as I have multiple forms, that will end up with duplicate numbers across tabs.

Is there a way to prefix each identifier with a word?

I tried to do this by combining using the tab name with the row number but couldn't get it to work.

Comment: I see two options: 1) Create a custom script to add a unique ID to each submission on the form submission.  2) you could use a QUERY() formula to query each and include a column for the tab name and then combine that with the timestamp in another column. To do the QUERY() option try adapting the [first formula in this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43056580/3354226)

Answer (score 1):

Each Form Responses has a unique Timestamp which will be unique. You can convert that into a string and use that as an identifier. Here's one such example (assuming cell A3 has the form response timestamp)

```
=REGEXREPLACE(TO_TEXT(A3), "\D", "")
```

Comment: That's great for unique identifiers, but what if I need it to be sequential? Can I set a prefix and starting number for the rows in each sheet?